# My font is appearing too high within its span

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to understand why the font in this span does not appear vertically centered. If you look at the highlighted span, you'll notice that while the top of the text is flush, the bottom is a couple of pixels from the bottom of the span. This has the effect of making the text not look vertically centered.

Things it is not:

Line height: Currently set to '1'. Any other value results in a larger line-height with the text still vertically offset.

Vertical-align: Changing the vertical align does nothing, regardless of how I set display (inline, inline-block, etc).

[image: Span highlighted]

Comment: Do you have some code to share ? Can we see this span parent style ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually vertically centered, because the bottom offset for letters such as **"j,q,g,p .."** - with a bottom part/descender. Just try to paste any text with those letters in "span" tag, like so:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <span>Eqpjg combinedqjpg</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I created this example for you https://jsfiddle.net/vfusz07z/1/. And vice versa if you have letters in the words/sentences that I mentioned above and at the same time you don't have capital letters there you'll see that text looks aligned to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You have no letters with descenders in your example. Try it with a word like "Tagcloud" or "Taj Mahal" - (letters g, j) then you'll see that it fills the whole height...

Answer (score 0):

Well it would appear that the font (Avenir Pro) just happens to be weirdly baselined.